# Invalid character around character 0 with JSON Serialization (Swift 3)

Tags: json, swift

I have a working link to some real-time stock price data, and I'm trying to import it into my Swift app. The HTML file containing the data is quite clean, except it begins with "//" before it lists the appropriate prices. I think that those characters are creating the "invalid character" error with JSON Serialization.

Here's my code that does the serialization. It crashes on the "return (try! JSONSerialization...") line

```
public class func query(statement: String) -> NSDictionary {
    let query = "\(prefix)NASDAQ:\(statement)"

    let jsonData = (String(describing: (contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: query)!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8))).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let result = { _ -> NSDictionary in
        if let data = jsonData {
            return (try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)) as! NSDictionary //error line
        }

        return NSDictionary()
    }()

    return result
}
```

This is all of the returned data:

```
// [ { "id": "33312" ,"t" : "T" ,"e" : "NYSE" ,"l" : "39.47" ,"l_fix" : "39.47" ,"l_cur" : "39.48" ,"s": "0" ,"ltt":"2:47PM EST" ,"lt" : "Nov 29, 2:47PM EST" ,"lt_dts" : "2016-11-29T14:47:29Z" ,"c" : "-0.07" ,"c_fix" : "-0.07" ,"cp" : "-0.16" ,"cp_fix" : "-0.16" ,"ccol" : "chr" ,"pcls_fix" : "39.54" } ]
```

Is there a way to "skip" the two characters at the beginning, or is there another approach to solving this issue that I'm not aware of? Thanks!

Comment: can i see a sample of the returned data from the server?

Comment: If I search up AAPL, this is all of the returned data: // [ { "id": "33312" ,"t" : "T" ,"e" : "NYSE" ,"l" : "39.47" ,"l_fix" : "39.47" ,"l_cur" : "39.48" ,"s": "0" ,"ltt":"2:47PM EST" ,"lt" : "Nov 29, 2:47PM EST" ,"lt_dts" : "2016-11-29T14:47:29Z" ,"c" : "-0.07" ,"c_fix" : "-0.07" ,"cp" : "-0.16" ,"cp_fix" : "-0.16" ,"ccol" : "chr" ,"pcls_fix" : "39.54" } ]

Comment: Please let us know if one of the answers worked for you by marking it as answer

Comment: I found the solution. Both of your answers ended up creating a substring out of the URL string, rather than of the contents of the URL, and then trying to JSON serialize the new data associated with the new URL string, which naturally didn't work. To solve this issue and delete the two "//" characters, I created a new String containing the contents of the URL using the "try String(contentsOf: url)" function and simply removing the first two items in the resultant String. Converting this String to data and then serializing it worked, and I was able to pass the NSDictionary through. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about trying to remove the "\" character like this:

```
public class func query(statement: String) -> NSDictionary {
      let prefix = ""
      let query = "\(prefix)NASDAQ:\(statement)"

      var data = String(describing: (contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: query)!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8))

      data = data.substring(from: data.characters.index(data.startIndex, offsetBy: 2))

      let jsonData = data.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

      let result = { _ -> NSDictionary in
         if let data = jsonData {
            let array = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray

            return array.count > 0 ? array[0] as? NSDictionary ?? NSDictionary() : NSDictionary()
         }

         return NSDictionary()
      }()

      return result
   }
```

Comment: This will also replace all `\\`within the JSON data.

Comment: i don't see any other \

Comment: True :-) But in theory.

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work. I'm still getting the same invalid character error... Perhaps there are some other characters in the data that are invalid? I didn't see any myself but it's possible.

Comment: I updated my answer it was \\ instead of // can you check again

Comment: Yes, I already accounted for that change. Still gives me the "invalid character around character 0" error.

Comment: I think the return is an array so you have an array with one item in it try jsonarry instead and then get the first item and cast it to a dictionary

Comment: @L. Messi check my answer now

Comment: This crashes on the same line (the try JSONSerialization one) with a new error: "fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Something looked like a 'true' but wasn't around character 0.""

Answer (score 0):

First you are trying to return an `NSDictionary`, but your data is an `Array` of dictionaries:

```
let result = { _ -> NSDictionary in
```

Use the following code to also cut off the first two characters using  `substring`:

```
var test = "// [ { \"id\": \"33312\" ,\"t\" : \"T\" ,\"e\" : \"NYSE\" ,\"l\" : \"39.47\" ,\"l_fix\" : \"39.47\" ,\"l_cur\" : \"39.48\" ,\"s\": \"0\" ,\"ltt\":\"2:47PM EST\" ,\"lt\" : \"Nov 29, 2:47PM EST\" ,\"lt_dts\" : \"2016-11-29T14:47:29Z\" ,\"c\" : \"-0.07\" ,\"c_fix\" : \"-0.07\" ,\"cp\" : \"-0.16\" ,\"cp_fix\" : \"-0.16\" ,\"ccol\" : \"chr\" ,\"pcls_fix\" : \"39.54\" } ] "

let result = test.substring(from: test.characters.index(test.startIndex, offsetBy: 2))

let data = result.data(using: .utf8)

var array = [[String:Any]]()
do {
    array = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [[String: Any]]
} catch {
    print(error)
}

print(array.first!)
```

Result:

```
["ltt": 2:47PM EST, "l_fix": 39.47, "lt_dts": 2016-11-29T14:47:29Z, "c_fix": -0.07, "lt": Nov 29, 2:47PM EST, "t": T, "pcls_fix": 39.54, "cp": -0.16, "ccol": chr, "id": 33312, "cp_fix": -0.16, "c": -0.07, "s": 0, "e": NYSE, "l": 39.47, "l_cur": 39.48]
```

Comment: This gives me another error: "Something looked like a 'true' but wasn't around character 0."

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: This doesn't crash, but it returns an empty array for me. It also has an error before the "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value" that causes the crash, which is: "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Something looked like a 'true' but wasn't around character 0.""

Comment: My code runs in Playground. Conclusion: Your data differs from the one you posted. Maybe ugly whitespaces or such.